# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare mss() (previously declared in *

Tags: php, function

I don't understand, the function doesn't exist, and even if I change it to some absurd names, it still doesn't work. Can anyone find the problem?

```
function mss($value){
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($value)));
    return $data;
}
```

*EDIT*: I forgot to  mention, its XAMPP

Answer (score 7):

That will mean that you've either defined the function in two separate spots, or your including the same file twice.

Use include_once/require_once instead of include/require.

Comment: @Rob just before you declare mss(), use this: var_dump(get_included_files()); Make sure there's no duplicate files being included.

Answer (score 5):

Ben Rowe's answer is almost assuredly the reason why it's happening.

I don't recommend this but you can always wrap your function in [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/function_exists)

```
if(!function_exists("mss")) {

    function mss($value){
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($value)));
        return $data;
    }

}
```

This solution is messy. It's almost always more preferable to find out WHY your file is being included twice or where this function is defined twice. But, for special circumstances this solution *could* be appropriate.

Comment: Yeah that can work. I didn't recommend it because it's usually an unnecessary performance hit.

Comment: @Rob Are you sure you're editing the right file? What does the exact error message say? What file/line was it originally declared and what file/line is it being redeclared?

Answer (score 1):

If you're keeping it in a separate file, are you including it more than once accidentally?

Answer (score 0):

include_once (not include) works as long as you have the function declared one time only in a separate .php file. Please double check that the Function is not mentioned elsewhere .

Answer (score 0):

You should : include_once
instead of : include

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?